Take a Range or Cell objects as parameters of a function
I want to take the Range or the Cell object as is, not a String representing the A1 notation of the Range or the Cell address.......
For example, I wanna target the use of my valorDesdeArriba () GAS function with an A1 address Google Sheets cell, as valorDesdeArriba (A1), not as valorDesdeArriba("A1")


In this Google Sheet Spreadsheet, I use my valorDesdeArriba() function for obtaining the "Consejeria de Economia, Hacienda y Empleo" value as result, because of the "B12" parameter String used (written in "A1" addressing code) for finding the first non-null cell value above the referenced cell
This is my Google Apps Script function for Google Sheet, valorDesdeArriba() in that I pretend to give the functionality of finding the first non-null value above a given Cell.
I try to target a valorDesdeArriba() use format, but I actually resulted on a valorDesdeArriba("") liked format. My question consist in how can I consecute that my function work with rows and cols for the proper  referenced, spite of a String value that reference to another cell, what  is that occurs me when I try to use my function as valorDesdeArriba(A1) spite of as valorDesdeArriba("A1").......... In case of valorDesdeArriba(A1) use, if I have a "B15" string value in that A1 cell, my function works with rows and cols of B15 cell, not with A1 such!!
function valorDesdeArriba (pCelda="A1") {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();

  var rngColumna;

  var vCelda;
  var vColumna;
  var vFila;
  var vHoja;
  var rngCelda;
  var vF;
  var stValor = "--";

  vHoja = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  rngCelda = vHoja.getRange(pCelda);
  vCelda = rngCelda.getCell(1,1);
  
  vColumna = vCelda.getColumn();
  vFila = vCelda.getRow();

  for (vF=vFila; vF>=1 && (stValor == "" || stValor == "--"); vF--) {
    rngColumna = vHoja.getRange(vF, vColumna);
    vCelda = rngColumna.getCell(1,1);

    stValor = vCelda.getValue();
  }

  return stValor;
}


from (deleted) comments:

looking at your script this can be solved very easily with native formula. would you be interested in such solution?
yes, thank you...

try:
=INDEX(IFERROR(LET(r, A2:C10, c, SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(r)), 
 HLOOKUP(c, {c; OFFSET(r, -(ROW(r)-2), )}, 
 BYCOL((r<>"")*ROW(r), LAMBDA(z, MAX(z))), 0)), "--"))


or:
=IFERROR(BYCOL(A2:C16, LAMBDA(x, CHOOSEROWS(TOCOL(x, 1), -1))), "--")


